# Has a Bond car ever survived a mission?

Tags: james-bond

James Bond has owned and destroyed many a car in his adventures, much to the chagrin of Q.

Bond has destroyed cars owned by MI:6, himself, and others. In this instance I am specifically looking for a car that was issued to Bond by MI:6.

Has any such car been issued and returned intact?

Comment: If I remember correctly he didn't use his BMW in Goldeneye much at all and just gave it to Jack Wade. But I don't exactly know if that was issued by MI:6 or if gifting it to a CIA fellow counts as "returning intact".

Comment: The problem is, though, that he also drives numerous "normal" cars in the films too, as can be read in [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_James_Bond_vehicles), many of which have also been provided to him by the British government or MI:6 and are left perfectly intact. But I assume you're only after the ones explicitly given to him by the Q branch.

Comment: @Napoleon Wilson Yes, I would be more interested in mission used cars provided by Q to have "all the usual refinements". That BMW would meet my criteria, I had forgotten he gave it to Jack.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes. Sometimes (although rarely) Bond's cars survive.

It's a little difficult to determine which cars were "issued" by MI6. But I've compiled a list of cars we can assume came from them (as opposed to just commandeered in the line of duty).

Below is a breakdown of James Bond's cars and whether they survive.

[Dr No.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._No_(film))

- Sunbeam Alpine : **Survived**

[From Russia With Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Russia_with_Love_(film))

- Bently Mark IV : **Survived**

[GoldFinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldfinger_(film))

- Aston Martin DB5 : Status unknown

[Thunderball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderball_(film))

- Aston Martin DB5 : Status unknown

[You only live Twice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Only_Live_Twice_(film))

- Toyota 2000 GT : **Survived**

[On Her Majesty's Secret Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_Her_Majesty%27s_Secret_Service_(film))

- Mercury Cougar : Major Damage
- Aston Martin DBS : Single bullet hole, but not destroyed.

[Diamonds Are Forever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamonds_Are_Forever_(film))

- Ford Mustang : Minor Damage

[The Man With the Golden Gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_with_the_Golden_Gun_(novel))

- AMC Hornet : Major Damage

[The Spy Who Loved Me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spy_Who_Loved_Me_(film))

- Lotus Esprit : **Survived** (totally awesomely)

[Moonraker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonraker_(film))

- Bentley 4½ Litre : Destroyed
- Bentley Mark VI : **Survives** in the movie (but destroyed in the novel)

[For Your Eyes Only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Your_Eyes_Only_(film))

- Lotus Esprit Turbo : Destroyed

[Octopussy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octopussy)

- Range Rover Classic : **Survived**

[A View To A Kill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_View_to_a_Kill)

- Ford LTD : **Survived**
- Rolls Royce Silver Cloud II : Destroyed

[The Living Daylights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Living_Daylights)

- Aston Martin V8 : Status Unknown

[License to Kill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licence_to_Kill)

- Lincoln Mark VII LSC: **Survived**

[GoldenEye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoldenEye)

- Aston Martin DB5 : **Survived**
- BMW Z3 : **Survived**

[Tomorrow Never Dies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomorrow_Never_Dies)

- Aston Martin DB5 : **Survived**
- BMW 750iL : Destroyed

[The World Is Not Enough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Is_Not_Enough)

- Aston Martin DB5 : **Survived**
- BMW Z8 : Destroyed

[Die Another Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_Another_Day)

- Ford Fairlane : **Survived**
- Aston Martin V12 Vanquish : Damaged but **Survives**

[Casino Royale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casino_Royale_(2006_film)) (the new one)

- Aston Martin DB5 : **Survives**
- Aston Martin DBS V12 : Destroyed

[Quantum of Solace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_of_Solace)

- Aston Martin DBS V12 : Damaged but **Survives**

[Skyfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyfall)

- Aston Martin DB5 : Destroyed

[Spectre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(2015_film))

- Aston Martin DB10 : Destroyed

Comment: Doesn't the classic DB5 get destroyed up in _Skyfall_? Or am I misremembering?

Comment: Yeah, the DB5 in Skyfall gets destroyed (this is referenced in Spectre). Also it's a shame that in Moonraker the Bentley Mark VI isn't destroyed, which really does show how much the film missed out.

Comment: The list of cars that survived is around 100% longer than I expected ;-)

Comment: @Snowman my thoughts exactly. hence why I asked the question!

Comment: Occam's razor: unless evidenced otherwise, it's the same DB5 in subsequent films?

Comment: @Snowman You're right. But the list of cars Bond drives is huge, often 3 or more per movie. I cut down the list to only cars that would conceivably have been issued to Bond. I think all the cars that M introduces (where he lists the gadgets) are destroyed 100% of the time. Can you think of a time where it wasn't?

Comment: @Coomie You mean Q, and yes, the one he just gives away in *Goldeneye* was explicitly issued by Q, as far as I remember. The car actually doesn't have *any* real use at all, it was decidedly anti-climactic.